# How to add Work Profile on Android 12 (OnePlus 7 Pro)

Tags: android-12, work-profiles

Apparently, Google has changed its software that handles Work Profile between v11 and v12.

In v11, it was handled by **Android Device Policy**, which was replaced by **App Device Policy**. The later works differently, instead of asking for credentials (email/password), it asks for a QR code supposedly provided by the company's IT department.

The issue is, the IT department doesn't have the ability to generate nor provide this QR code. I am the Workspace Admin myself and I don't have such feature.

This article helped me make sense of this issue, but I haven't found a clue for a proper solution yet.

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Q-A/Unable-to-configure-Android-quot-work-profile-quot-with-google/m-p/393176

Is there a way to setup a Work Profile (with the ability to install different apps on each profile, e.g: install the same app twice and have it configured differently)?

If not, is this issue solved with Android 13?

I'm kind of stuck with this, really didn't expect to run into that when buying a new device, the benefits of having installed the same app multiple times is incredible, and made my life so much easier with all those OAuth logins everywhere. (and organise my "Desk" differently with folders for personal/work)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. AFAIK, a Work Profile will be automatically created when adding a new account using a Google Workspace email. Was it not working?

Comment: Not since Android 12, it used to work as simply as that, but that was before.
Now, it requires some MDM, and makes everything much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at many topics for hours, I came across https://f-droid.org/en/ and [Shelter](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.typeblog.shelter/) which allowed me to do that fairly easily.

The main downside of this alternative is that you have to install a software that's essentially admin (although not ROOT) of your phone, and trust the open source not to mess with you.

Other alternatives I found ([Insular, Island](https://alternativeto.net/software/shelter-app/)) were also open source, but Shelter has more features.